# c sharp type pattern causes compiler error

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following catch statement:

```
 catch (CustomException e) when (e.InnerException is MySqlException ex && ex.Number == 1062)
 {
     // handle duplicate inserts
 }
```

This never filters out the exception I need and the statement:

```
e.InnerException is MySqlException ex && ex.Number == 1062
```

Causes a compiler error when I watch it with the message: "internal error in the c# compiler" (see image below).
[image]

Changing this to the below works:

```
catch (CustomException e) when (e.InnerException is MySqlException && ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException)e.InnerException).Number == 1062)
 {
     // handle duplicate inserts
 }
```

Can anyone tell me why the first usage does not work? this is part of the documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#-type-pattern-

Here is my dotnet --info results

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.503
 Commit:    4c506e0f35

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.503\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.7
  Commit:  cca5d72d48

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.503 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: Most likely the adhoc compiler that the debugger is using in your IDE doesn't support pattern matching like this. Why the original statement doesn't catch your exception I don't know, can you post a full set of details about the `CustomException` instance you have?

Comment: This is a relatively new language feature. So which language version are you using?

Comment: `Causes a compiler error ` what's the error?

Comment: As requested, updated the question with the error message I get in the watch window.

Comment: Please post the exception _as text_ and not as an image.  An exception message in an image cannot be searched.

Comment: Hi @SuemayahEldursi did you find the reason of the behavior?, did